# Solutions of $\sigma(p^n)=\sigma(q^m)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

The following equation

$$
\sigma(P^n)=\sigma(Q^m)
$$

has only the trivial solution

$$
P=Q, m=n,
$$

for $P,Q$ irreducible polynomials of degree $>1$ in the ring 
$$
GF(2)[t]
$$

where  for any $A \in GF(2)[t]$

$$
\sigma(A) = \sum_{d \mid A} d
$$

Question: What happens over the integers. More precisely:

What are the solutions (besides $p=q,m=n$)
 (or what can be said about the solutions, besides $m \equiv n \pmod{2}$ )
of the equation

$$
\sigma(p^n) = \sigma(q^m)
$$

for odd prime numbers $p,q$ and positive integers $m,n$

where

`$$
\sigma(n) = \sum_{0<d, d \mid n} d.
$$`

Comment: In other words, $(p^r-1)/(p-1)=(q^s-1)/(q-1)$. Have you looked in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory? I'm pretty sure this equation is discussed there. 

Comment: The equation does not seems to be in my copy of Guy's book
(my copy  buyed august 1996).

The equation does not seems to appear in classical Mordell's book 
`Diophantine Equations`.




Comment: MR0118701 (22 no.9472)
Makowski, A. Schinzel, A.
Sur l'\'equation ind\'etermin\'ee de R. Goormaghtigh. (French)
Mathesis 68 1959 128–142.

R. Goormaghtigh conjectured that the only solution of 
$N=1+x+\cdots+x^m=1+y+\cdots+y^n$, $m>n>1$, $y>x>1$,
 are $N=31$, $y=5$, $x=2$, $m=4$, $n=2$ and $N=8191$, $y=90$, $x=2$, $m=12$, $n=2$. 
The authors prove several special cases of this conjecture.
Reviewed by P. Erd\H{o}s.



Comment: I detected the following misprint in my copy of Guy's book:  In Page 158, line 12
R. Goormachtigh  should be
`R. Goormaghtigh`.
Google was unable to find something on the former; I have not tried the latter.



Comment: There is a little bit of information about the question at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goormaghtigh_conjecture and the most recent (3rd) edition of Guy's book has a brief discussion in Problem B25 on pages 124-125. I'm not aware of anything more recent but I could have missed something. Might be worth searching arXiv for Goormaghtigh, or searching MathSci if you have access. 

Comment: Kaoru Motose observed that:

$$
n > m \geq 3
$$

implies

$$
(m^n-1)/(m-1) > (n^m-1)/(n-1)
$$
